# Which brewing podcasts do you listen to?

Tags: beer, media

Which are the essential podcasts that should be on my ipod right now?

Answer (score 10):

I listen to [Basic Brewing Radio](http://www.basicbrewing.com/index.php?page=radio)

Comment: Can't agree enough!  James does a great job of making things clear for the noob, but interesting to the more experienced brewer. And he doesn't spend the entire podcast getting hammered and blathering off topic like some other podcast I've tried.

Answer (score 6):

Brew Strong, The Sunday Session, and The Jamil Show.  All are on [The Brewing Network](http://www.thebrewingnetwork.com/).

Answer (score 3):

This one is still kinda new, but [Brewing TV](http://www.brewingtv.com/) is a fave of mine.